# Why string concatenation with pip line return nothing(empty string) in java?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

**Why string concatenation with pip line return nothing(empty string) in java?**

```
String product="";
for(Tar t:tars){
    product.concat(t.product.concat("|"));
}
System.out.println(product);
```

result is just nothing(empty string).

Comment: You have to assign the result of `concat()` to `product`, i.e. `product = product.concat(...)`

Comment: @HodeCode For my comment to be an answer, I would have to explain why...

Comment: @Baz Yeah but not much! All you need is something like Strings are immutable, hence that method returns a String created to represent the modification requested (eg. concat)? But anyway, I upvoted your comment!

Comment: @HodeCode Yeah, I know. I was just too lazy to formulate a proper answer. Thanks for the upvote anyways :) Besides, I am going for the "Pundit" badge :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String#concat` returns a concatenated String, it doesn't modify it. Strings are immutable in Java.

So...

```
product = product.concat(t.product.concat("|"));
```

But, I suggest using [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) where String copying happens in a loop.

Comment: Prefer `StringBuilder` to `StringBuffer` because the latter is thread-safe, which causes it to take a slight performance hit.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't meant to suggest StringBuffer either, but eh - happens.

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringBuilder` instead.

```
StringBuilder product=new StringBuilder();
for(Tar t:tars){
            product.append(t.product).append("|");
}
System.out.println(product.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If the collection is fairly large, I would recommend using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build the desired string, instead of using string concatenation. It will improve performance, albeit slightly.

See also [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java).

Also, straight from the horse's mouth,

[`String#concat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29):

> Concatenates the specified string to the end of this string.
>
> If the length of the argument string is `0`, then this `String` object is
>   returned. Otherwise, a new `String` object is created, representing a
>   character sequence that is the concatenation of the character sequence
>   represented by this `String` object and the character sequence
>   represented by the argument string.